# <script> element will not execute JS if it's a module on DOM re-insertion

Tags: javascript, html

It seems that the browser will not re-run a Javascript module if it has been previously loaded from the same address, even if that  element has already been removed from DOM. Is there any way to re-run the code?

See code snippet below - the script runs when the page is loaded. Remove button removes the script element, but when another script element is created and inserted, the code is not executed:

```
<script type="module" src="./t.js"></script>
<script>
   function add(){
       const s = document.createElement('script');
       s.type='module';
       s.src='./t.js';
       document.body.prepend(s)
   }
   function remove(){
       document.querySelector(`script[src='./t.js']`).remove();
   }
</script>

<button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

```
// t.js
import * from 'example.com/blah';
window.alert('Hi')
```

Comment: Just use a different address? `\`./t.js?uniqueID=${Math.random()}\``. But there are _much better_ alternatives. Can you change `t.js`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Hmm that's an interesting workaround, could try that. The scenario is a SPA router that will render different HTML that might include module script tags. Navigating first time to that page works fine but re-navigation breaks. Would like an as generally applicable option as possible. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to reconstruct the `<script type="module>` element without referencing the `src` attribute, by fetching the text content of the script resource and inserting it as `textContent` of a new `<script type="module">` element.

```
// s is a HTMLScriptElement you wish to re-run

function rerunModule(s) {
    fetch(s.src).then(async r => {
        const ns = document.createElement('script')
        ns.type = 'module'
        ns.textContent = await r.text()
        document.body.prepend(ns)
    })
}
```

Note that this method will make it difficult to debug in the DevTools, as it will not show up in the Sources tab.